# regex match words which may or may not have full stops

Tags: regex

I have a regex which matches a varying number of words

```
var re = new RegExp(/^0\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}\s\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,10}\s([A-Z]{2,2})\s([A-Z]{2,2})\s([A-Z]{2,2})\s([A-Z]{2,2})$/g);
```

Regex result which is working found sentence as follows

```
0 29.09.16 ISSUED FOR APPROVAL AND REVIEW MH SB CS MT
```

Regex does not work for the following sentences

```
0 29.09.16 ISSUED FOR APPROVAL AND REVIEW MHW SB CS MT
0 29.09.16 ISSUED FOR APPROVAL AND REVIEW M.H.W SB CS MT
0 29.09.16 ISSUED FOR APPROVAL AND REVIEW M.HBE SB CS MT
```

I think the problem is with the last four sets of initials which may or may not include full stops

Any help with modifying the regex for the last four sets of varying initials will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: `/0\s\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\s[A-z ]+\s([\.A-Z]{2,5})\s([A-Z]{2})\s([A-Z]{2})\s([A-Z]{2})/g`.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/22Nj9N/1

Basically your expression expects 2 characters only for the last 4 groups. So I also added the `.` to the accepted matches and up to 5 chars.

Comment: Regex works thank you, with the exception of initials with three full stops 0 23.09.16 ISSUED FOR APPROVAL AND REVIEW R.D.P. SB CS MT

Comment: Yes if you look in regex there is this part `[\.A-Z]{2,5}` that allows only 5 chars, so put 6 instead of 5!

Comment: I changed the 5 to a six, which works.  Except the console reports back the initials as R D P instead of R.D.P.  Would you know why it puts spaces in, instead of the full stops?  thank you

Comment: I made the change here https://regex101.com/r/22Nj9N/2, and you can inspect from the right panel "Match information" that the group is well matched `R.D.P.`. So it must be somewhere else in your code ;)